# ScrollView with PageControl in Storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uipagecontrol

I have three charts that I want to be able to scroll through with page control in a scroll view and I was wondering what the best way to set this up would be. Most of the tutorials I have seen have programmatically setup the views, but in order to use charts I had to create `UIViews` in storyboard already, so I was wondering what the best way to setup the `scrollView` would be so that the charts are each on a separate page?

[image]

Relevant lines of code are below. Do I need to drag the UIViews containing the charts somewhere else? Or can it not be done on storyboard?

```
import UIKit
import Charts

class ChartsViewController: UIViewController {

    // MARK: Types

    enum TimePeriod: Int {
        case day = 0
        case week = 1
        case month = 2
        case year = 3
    }

    // MARK: Properties

    var period: TimePeriod = .day {
        didSet {
            print(self.period)
        }
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var pageControl: UIPageControl!
    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
    @IBOutlet weak var pieChart: PieChartView!
    @IBOutlet weak var segmentedControl: UISegmentedControl!
    @IBOutlet weak var barChart: BarChartView!
    @IBOutlet weak var lineChart: LineChartView!

    func lineChartUpdate() {
        var lineChartEntry = [ChartDataEntry]()
        for i in 0 ..< 15 {
            let value = ChartDataEntry(x: Double(i), y: Double(i))
            lineChartEntry.append(value)
        }
        let line1 = LineChartDataSet(values: lineChartEntry, label: "Category 1")
        let data = LineChartData(dataSets: [line1])
        lineChart.data = data
        lineChart.chartDescription?.text = "Line Chart"

        lineChart.notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    func configurePageControl() {
        self.pageControl.numberOfPages = 3
        self.pageControl.currentPage = 0
    }

    @IBAction func renderCharts(_ sender: UISlider) {
        pieChartUpdate()
        barChartUpdate()
    }

    @IBAction func segmentedControlSelectedIndexDidChange(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
        self.period = TimePeriod(rawValue: sender.selectedSegmentIndex)!
    }

    // MARK: UIViewController

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        configurePageControl()
        pieChartUpdate()
        barChartUpdate()
        lineChartUpdate()
        scrollView.addSubview(pieChart)
        scrollView.addSubview(barChart)
        scrollView.addSubview(lineChart)
    }

    @IBAction func pageChange(_ sender: UIPageControl) {

    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create the views in xib and add then programmatically in scrollview.

**Example:**

You have three Views.

view1

view2

view2

You can add them to scrollview  as:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad() 
    view1 = View1(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 100))
    scrollView.addSubview(view1!)
    view2 = View2(frame: CGRect(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 522))
    scrollView.addSubview(view2!)
    view3 = View3(frame: CGRect(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.width*2, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: height))
    scrollView.addSubview(view3!)
}
```